# Windows 8 or Nvidia issue: Part of screen fades out to gray

Tags: windows-8, video, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, grayscale

I have this very weird issue that occurs on my machine, and it's easy to reproduce:

**Method 1:**

1. Go to Youtube or another video site
2. play a video
3. the rest of the screen fades out to gray
4. The video element itself is still in color

**Method 2:**

1. Play a video game where part of the screen is more static than the rest
2. Ex Dota2: As you play, the bottom portion of the screen will fade to gray
3. The main portion of the screen where the "action" is will remain in color

**Method 3:**

1. Go to Netflix and scroll through one of the carousels
2. As you scroll, the rest of the screen will fade to gray
3. The carousel that you interact with will remain in color

I am not sure if it's the:

- video card: Geforce GTX 760
- monitor: Acer
- OS: Windows 8.1 64bit.

It's driving me crazy!

I have searched for this all around, and have only noticed it for maybe the last month or two - perhaps it's a new feature or something.

I am fairly sure it's a software or hardware setting and not a bug, as the fade out to grayscale is not random but seemingly intentional.

Also - I am unable to take a screenshot of it, as when I do, it of course shows full color across the whole monitor.

Instead here is a picture comparison taken with my phone, notice that the same video plays in color while the rest of the screen fades out.

(... removed as I only have REP on Stack overflow)

Comment: Heh, great find. Could you perhaps add your displays exact model number so that it can be found more easily?

Comment: Of course! This was from an Acer B6 Series widescreen monitor, the exact model is Acer B6 B296CLbmiidprz Black 29"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trial and error, I have discovered the issue:

Acer monitors have a feature called "**Detect Video**", which apparently will attempt to determine video playback and then proceed to fade out the rest of the screen into grayscale. Unfortunately, this feature also affects video games.

So to fix I went into monitor setup menu and disabled this feature - set Detect Video to **NO**.

Comment: what a terrible feature, thank you for helping me find it!

Comment: unbelievable, who thought this would be a desirable feature???